# How to convert PCM to MP3?

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, pcm

I am in the process of converting PCM to MP3 player. It does not work well to convert PCM files with 20KHz to MP3. What's the problem?

[image]

[image]

And this is my code:

```
using (var retMs = new MemoryStream())
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filename)))
        using (var rdr = new WaveFileReader(ms))
        using (var wtr = new LameMP3FileWriter(retMs, rdr.WaveFormat, 128))
        {
            rdr.CopyTo(wtr);
            File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Mix.mp3", retMs.ToArray());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At 128k, MP3 encoders use a lowpass filter around 17 kHz.  Anything above it is dropped.

If retaining frequencies on the extreme ends of audible is important, you shouldn't be using a lossy codec at all... and certainly not MP3.